# PHP/Mysql array_pop missing first value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Basically what happens is this:

A person goes to a specific gallery, say GalleryID=42. I do a query to grab all of the images in that gallery (with the value of GalleryID=42), and do a separate query to grab all of the comments associated with that gallery (for example GalleryID=42).  There may only be 4 comments total on 3 different pictures out of 400 total images.

As I loop through the images with a do/while loop, and display them, I search the array of comments that have been placed for each picture as it loops. If it finds the picture ID that matches a specific picture, it displays the comment values (Comment, CommentAuthor, and CommentDate).

Here is the query for the images:

```
SELECT * FROM GalleryData WHERE GalleryID = 42
```

And the query for the comments:

```
SELECT Comment, CommentAuthor, CommentDate, ID FROM Comments WHERE CategoryID=42
```

Then I use this code to put the comments in the reusable query:

```
while(($Comments[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsComments)) || array_pop($Comments));
```

Then I use this to this to loop through the array to find the comments associated with the particular picture

```
foreach($Comments as $comment) 
{
  if($comment['ID'] == $row_rsGalleries['ID']) 
  {
    echo '<p>'.$comment['Comment'].' - '.$comment['CommentAuthor'].'</p>';
  }
}
```

Problem is, that this code seems to not include the very first comment in the query.

Now, this is one of the first projects I have done something like this, and I am not a php/mysql expert, a novice user.

When I run the query, it comes up with 4 results, but the array only includes 3, the first result is missing.

Comment: It takes all of the values from a Mysql query and puts it into a reusable array that I can use over and over.  The values come from:

Comment: Well for one thing, you're going to be appending `bool` values onto `$Comments`... `mysql_fetch_assoc(...) || array_pop(...)` is evaluated before assignment, and the result will always be a bool.

Comment: Why do you have `|| array_pop($Comments)` ??

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($Comments)` after the loop?

Comment: Is there a possibility of just putting the comments into the query that grabs all of the pictures?  Keep in mind there may be 10 comments per picture?  Like possibly creating a value of comments with each value separate by a ~ for example?

Answer (score 5):

This construct looks totally crazy to me. I don't understand why it would cut off the first element, but I don't really feel inclined to even spend the time to find out: You need to fix that statement. Using `||` in this context is never going to give you the result you want.

Can you describe what this is supposed to do?

Comment: It takes the values from a recordset:


mysql_select_db($database_connUser, $connUser);
$query_rsComments = sprintf("SELECT Comment, CommentAuthor, CommentDate, ID FROM Comments WHERE CategoryID = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_rsComments, "int"));
$rsComments = mysql_query($query_rsComments, $connUser) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsComments = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsComments);
$totalRows_rsComments = mysql_num_rows($rsComments);

Comment: @Randy I don't understand what the `|| array_pop($Comments)` part is supposed to do. I think you can just leave that out and it should work

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need the pop code?

```
while($rsComment = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsComments)) {
    $Comments[] = $rsComment;
}
```

Doesn't this do everything you need with the advantage of being much more verbose?

**Edit** The reason your code doesn't work is when the while evaluates to false to stop the loop, it runs the array_pop and this removes 1 element from the array.

Comment: Note that when the first element is popped off, a bool is popped back on to the end.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row if there are rows present and it returns `false` if there are no more rows.

So

```
while(($Comments[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsComments)) || array_pop($Comments));
```

will look like:

```
while(true || array_pop($Comments));
```

for the first 4 rows. Now the `||` is short circuited, the pop does not happen. After this when there are no more rows left, `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns `false` which gets pushed in the array and then `array_pop` gets executed which removes the last added element (`false`).

So effectively the `|| array_pop($Comments)` removes the final boolean value pushed in the array, ensuring that the array has only the rows returned by `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: Incorrect; It's more like `while ($Comments[] = (true || array_pop(...)));` This is an important distinction, as the `array_push` values pushed onto the array are **always bools**.

Comment: Basically what happens is this:  A person goes to a specific gallery, say GalleryID=42.  I do a query to grab all of the comments associated with value of ID=42.  In the gallery, there are 400 some images.  Comments have been made on only a few pictures.  As I loop through the images and display them, I search the array for comments that have been placed for each picture as it loops.  If it finds the picture ID that matches a specific picture, it displays the comment values (Comment, CommentAuthor, and CommentDate).Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure how this works at all.

At first I assumed it would fill the array with `bool` values, but after thinking about it, **the loop should never terminate**.

It will eventually equate to `while(($array[] = array_pop($array)));`, and for a non-empty array, this will **spin forever**:

The following never terminates:

```
<?php

// Simulate MySQL_fetch_assoc; return false when no more results
function fetch($results) {
    if (count($results))
        return array_pop($results);
    return false;
}

$Comments = array();
$rsComments= array(array(3), array(4), array(5), array(6));

while (($Comments[] = fetch($rsComments) || array_pop($Comments)));

// $Comments = array(true,true,true,true,true,...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put in a counter; for instance:  $counter=3  Then your while statement contains that counter, like this:

while ($count < 3) {   (Your count starts at 0, so although you have a total of 4 items, 0 counts as one of them.  Your program will only count up to 3 with the array you have.)

I cannot help correct anything else in your code because I am too new to programming myself, but at least that will help you keep from having a never-ending loop.